# SSL solution for multi host web portal on IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, iis-7, ssl

My portal is currently work as multiple domain point to same application.

abc.com, bce.com, cde.com etc all coming to same server and content created based on host.

is there any solution for to use SSL. as I know ssl is domain dependent, so any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If displayed content is always the same, anyway used url, you could do a little trick:
-Redirect everybody to one URL 
-Redirect to https.

The good: One cheap SSL certificate, one public ip.

The bad: when people need https, then they all come to same url, which may be different from the one they came in.

You didn't specify if it's internet faced.
If it's internal web site, you could deploy a PKI, like from Microsoft, and so generate as many free certificate as you need.

Comment: actually; content which generated depends on url and also is different. it is not just a website.

Comment: I am afraid you are stuck to get one certificate and so ip per website. You can reduce this through wildcards & SAN, but won't fit in just one certificate in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about hosting all the websites on the same IP and port there are just two options.

1. Use a certificate with multiple Subject Alternate Names. These are called Unified Communications Certificates. This is the most widely supported method but also the most expensive. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929395
2. Wait for IIS8 which supports Server Name Indication extensions for TLS. Unfortunately this is not supported on Windows XP running Internet Explorer (Firefox works though) so may not suit depending on your target audience.

SAN certificates are expensive the more domains you add.

Lewis

Comment: thanks lewis. can you also answer that : i have both naked domains (abc.com, def.com etc) and also wildcard subdomains (*.zed.com). Is it supported? Currently i have 150 domains and subdomains pointing to the same IP. As I know UCC supports up to 49 domains.

Comment: I haven't seen UCC certificates used like that before but with there being so many CAs out there, I expect there's at least one that does permit that. In reality what you want is either going to be extremely expensive in terms of certificates or in terms of IP addresses. Until SNI is supported more widely (could take years yet with XP/IE not being supported) you're asking too much of a single IP. Your final option is probably to host the secure sites on different ports. It's not pretty but your options are limited depending on budget.